# How to Use Apple Provided Icons

Tags: ios, iphone, icons

How do I find and use Apple provided icons? I'm specifically trying to use Apple's share icon. I know I can download an image like it and use that, but I figure there's a provided icon kit for typical Apple functions?

I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Iconography.html) on Apple's developer site:

> iOS provides a lot of small icons—representing common tasks and types
>   of content—for use in tab bars, toolbars, navigation bars, and Home
>   screen quick actions. It’s a good idea to use the built-in icons as
>   much as possible because users already know what they mean.

I don't have a nav-tab bar of any sort. Does this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked multiple times at StockOverflow. Unfortunately it's not possible to use them out side of bars

> iOS defines lots of standard small icons, such as Refresh, Action,
>   Add, and Favorites. As much as possible, you should use these buttons
>   and icons to represent standard tasks in your app. (To learn more
>   about the standard buttons and icons you can use in bars, see Toolbar
>   and Navigation Bar Buttons and Tab Bar Icons.)

Comment: Well, that's a shame. If I download an icon that looks like it and use it outside a bar, I assume I'm violating some kind of Apple user interface guideline rule and will get rejected if I try to submit the app?

Comment: Not sure. I've seen multiple Apps with nearly identical icons. So I assume it must be possible. Sometimes Apple does not make it easy for us...

Comment: There is this widely-used utility to extract icons: https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor  I've never heard of a rejection due to using icons identical to Apple's

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the icon files:

Open the url https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/ in your browser (I'm using Chrome), on a Mac with retina display.

Right click on each icon and press `Save Image As`. You can use this image as the `@2x` icon.

If you load the page on a non-retina display, the icons will be 1x resolution.